# Get first letter of index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
            population
n
France      66.03
Italy       59.83
```

I want to get the first letter of the index label, for each row, and set it as a new column so that I can start doing analysis with it. How can I do this?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
def get_first_letter(row):
    return row[0]
df1 = df.reset_index()
df1.first_letter = df1.n.apply(get_first_letter)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`get_level_values` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html#pandas-index-get-level-values) to obtain the index label. Then [use `str[0]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) to obtain the first letter:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'population':[66.03,59.83]}, index=pd.Series(['France','Italy'], name='n')); df
Out[29]: 
        population
n                 
France       66.03
Italy        59.83

In [30]: df['first_letter'] = df.index.get_level_values('n').str[0]; df
Out[30]: 
        population first_letter
n                              
France       66.03            F
Italy        59.83            I
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. There are two things which you may do differently

1. use lambda or list comprehension instead of the named function
2. set the index directly instead of reseting it.

Like this:

```
df1.n.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

or

```
df1.set_index(pd.Index((x[0] for x in df1.index)))
```